# Image color not updating during coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to get something similar to the example given in the Unity documentation for coroutines. In the example an image is slowing fading when we update its alpha value:

```
IEnumerator Fade() {
    for (float f = 1f; f >= 0; f -= 0.1f) {
        Color c = renderer.material.color;
        c.a = f;
        renderer.material.color = c;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Here's my code, with QTE_Image being an `Image` component.

```
while (!QTE_Finished) {
    Color temp_Color = QTE_Image.color;
    temp_Color.a = (255/(QTE_MultiplierMax - QTE_MultiplierMin))*QTE_Multiplier - (255/((QTE_MultiplierMax/QTE_MultiplierMin)-1));
    Debug.Log (temp_Color.a); 
    QTE_Image.color = temp_Color;
    yield return null;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a formula to calculate the next alpha value (the formula is working, the `Debug.Log (temp_Color.a)` is returning the expected value). However, the image is not updated until the end of the while loop.

Comment: You mean the [Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) component, right? If so, please tag the language you are using too. No one knows which one. Also, You just want to fade the image alpha from 1 to 0 over time?

Comment: I realized the issue by reading your comment. The alpha value was going from 0 to 255 while it should go from 0 to 1.

Comment: Nice. That's what I wanted to make sure you got right. I hope it is now fixed. If not you can comment and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that the `Color` struct uses decimal color values ranging from 0 to 1, whereas your formula returns an alpha value from 0 to 255.

Remove the `255*` from your formula, or use the `Color32` struct (which uses a range of ints from 0 to 255).

With `Color` struct:

`temp_Color.a = (QTE_Multiplier - QTE_MultiplierMin) / (QTE_MultiplierMax - QTE_MultiplierMin);`

With `Color32` struct:

`temp_Color.a = (int) (255 * (QTE_Multiplier - QTE_MultiplierMin) / (QTE_MultiplierMax - QTE_MultiplierMin));`